# How to make an html element contain text when an ASP:Button is pressed?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, html

I've got a DIV which contains some text in it.

Ive also got an asp:Button, which when pressed I would like to retrieve this text. However, it appears that as soon as I press the button, the DIV's contents is reset - most likely due to postback.

The DIV has got runat=server". Does anyone have any idea as to what may be done to make this DIV retain its contents on pressing the button? The data is manipulated countless times before the button is pressed, so I would like to try avoiding updating a Session every time.

Comment: Are you changing div's content on the client side (with JavaScript)?

Comment: Yes, it's being altered through jQuery.

Comment: have a look at: http://www.codedigest.com/Articles/ASPNET/320_Doing_or_Raising_Postback_using___doPostBack()_function_from_Javascript_in_AspNet.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
getText = function(){
    alert($("#<%=Panel1.ClientID%>").text());
    return false;
}   

<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">

</asp:Panel>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClientClick="return getText();" ... />
```

You can also try this:

```
$("#<%=Button1.ClientID%>").click(function(){
    alert($("#div1").text());
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. How exactly would I be able to access the text in the code-bhind, using your method?

Comment: The text of the div? You just need to add `runat="server"` to the div, or you can use a Panel (renders a DIV).

Comment: I'm not sure I'm fully understanding how the onClientClick is going to help in retaining the text. Isn't this done through Javascript? Or is the method called from the code-behind?

Comment: By using runat server, you can reference the control from code-behind. If you use a DIV (Literal), you can get the text like this: div1.InnerText

Comment: @JamesJohnson Changes made on the client side won't get to the server, so the old value will be returned.

Comment: @jakubka: that's not true. If its running at the server, changes on the client will be available on the server after a postback.

Comment: @JamesJohnson: That aplies only to the form controls. InnerHTMLs of the 'classic' HTML tags like <div> are not send to the server. This is true simply because postback is basically the same as submitting form.

Comment: @jakubka: If you add runat="server" to a DIV it resolveS to a Literal control, which has an InnerText property.

Comment: @JamesJohnson: I perfectly understand what are you saying. My point is, that if you change content of the div rendered by Literal control on the client side, the changed content won't get to the server after postback. To be 100% sure, I just tried it and it really works like this.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your input! I decided to postpone the implementation of this feature for now, due to a change in requirements beyond my control. Many thanks to all of you for the contributions.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be grabbing button click event in your makrkup, store your DIV content in a hidden field, then fire postback manually in your button click.

Comment: Do you think you could elaborate on this? :) Looks promising!

Answer (score 0):

Try using an asp:Panel. It renders as a DIV and you have access to all of its properties at all points in the page life cycle.

Answer (score 0):

another way is to use Ajax. specifically -  `updatepanel` control

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot use AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

You can't read your DIV's content because it is not send to the server in the postback. Only values of form elements (`<input>`, `<textarea>`, `<select>`, etc.) are send.

If you really want to read DIV's content, you can copy it to the hidden input (as wrote Kavousi).

Just add hidden field to your page:

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hidden" runat="server" />
```

And then in code behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        Page.Form.Attributes["onsubmit"] = string.Format(@"$(""#{0}"").val($(""#{1}"").html());", hidden.ClientID, div.ClientID);
    }
}
```

(`div` is your div's name).

You can then read div's content by reading `hidden.Value`.

Answer (score 0):

You can store you DIV content in a hidden field by calling a JavaScript function in onClientClick event of the button - it will execute just before OnClick event, before postback. This way, there's no need to fire postback manually.

Let's say you have one div, one hidden field and button with onClientClick and OnClick events. You use simple JavaScript function for the job:

```
<div id="myDiv" runat="server" ></div>
<asp:Button ID="btnGetDiv" runat="server" Text="Get div value" OnClick="getValueOnServer" OnClientClick="setHiddenFieldF()"/>
<asp:HiddenField ID="hf" runat="server" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    function setHiddenFieldF() {
        var nevValue = document.getElementById('<%= myDiv.ClientID %>').innerHTML;
        document.getElementById('<%= hf.ClientID %>').value = nevValue;            
    }
</script>
```

Then, on the server, just use the value of the hidden field.

Comment: This would also work, if you fix the `"myDiv"` to real `ClientID` in the `getElementByID` function.

Comment: But I think my solution is better, because it will copy div's content to hidden field before every postback, so you don't have to call the `setHiddenFieldF` before clicking every button.

Comment: @jakubka: you're right, I've edited myDiv, although it worked even without it, because in my example I don't use any kind of content placeholder (master page, user control etc), so control names remains unchanged.